# Confluent Kafka Python API for Consumer - seek()

Tags: python, apache-kafka, consumer

I am tying to have an endpoint to reset partition using consumer.seek() but *feeling sick* for trying different things and nothing works, also confluent documentation for kafka is bit weird (Specifically python API)

Link for document I am referring to:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.seek

I am not clear with following statement in document:

```
partition (TopicPartition) – Topic+partition+offset to seek to.
```

I tried following in my code but it gives one or other error:

```
partitions = consumer.assignment()
for p in partitions:
consumer.seek(p)
```

I also tried with:

```
consumer.seek(1,0)
```

Keep getting various errors:

```
TypeError: expected cimpl.TopicPartition
```

I will really appreciate if any suggestions. Also may I know what is the process to the the document updated with correct information so that it helps to fellow developers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should review the help docs associated with `confluent_kafka.cimpl.TopicPartition` -

```
class TopicPartition(builtins.object)
 |  TopicPartition is a generic type to hold a single partition and various information about it.
 |  
 |  It is typically used to provide a list of topics or partitions for various operations, such as :py:func:`Consumer.assign()`.
 |  
 |  .. py:function:: TopicPartition(topic, [partition], [offset], [metadata], [leader_epoch])
 |  
 |    Instantiate a TopicPartition object.
 |  
 |    :param string topic: Topic name
 |    :param int partition: Partition id
 |    :param int offset: Initial partition offset
 |    :param string metadata: Offset metadata
 |    :param int leader_epoch: Offset leader epoch
 |    :rtype: TopicPartition
```

To create an object with this type, you need at minimum to supply the topic name.

When I've written code that needs to call `seek()`, I've generally been in need of seeking for a particular timestamp (milliseconds-since-epoch), so I use the Consumer function `offsets_for_times()` somewhat like this:

```py
seekstamp = int(datetime.strptime("2023-01-01T00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").strftime("%s")) * 1000

start_partitions = [TopicPartition("my.topic.name", i, seekstamp) for i in range(0, 8)]

offsets = consumer.offsets_for_times(start_partitions)
consumer.assign(offsets)

messages = consumer.consume(BATCHSIZE, timeout=60)
```

Note that if you *subscribe* to the topic, you'll get messages from the timestamp of when you subscribed. If you want to consume from the specific offset or a timestamp, you need to use the `assign()` method.